# Как удалить созданную дампом схему?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Развёртывал дамп БД и была создана схема, но что то пошло не так.

Решил всё снести и заново переустановить дамп, но не могу удалить уже созданную схему.

Подскажите, как удалить схему?

Не могу, потому что в гугле не нашёл команды. Нашёл команду удалить юзера и якобы это автоматически удаляет все схемы по юзеру. Но не могу проверить, то ли это, что мне нужно.

Comment: А почему не можете, или - как вы удаляете?

Comment: не могу потому что в гугле не нашёл команды, нашёл команду удалить юзера и якобы это автоматически удаляет схемы по юзеру, но при создании схемы выскачила ошибка так как такая схему уже есть

Comment: Не совсем понял, что пошагово? Я и не смотрю глобально. После правки, соответствует всё положению вешей вашего вопроса? Подтвердите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Смотрите пошагово (мне дали набор команд):
1 Получаю дамп и распаковываю его в директорию
2 CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE STAGE2 DATAFILE 'stage2.dat' SIZE 100M AUTOEXTEND ON;
3 ........ другие команды
4 DROP USER STAGE2 CASCADE; ... удаляем пользователя
5 CREATE USER STAGE2 IDENTIFIED BY STAGE2 DEFAULT TABLESPACE STAGE2 QUOTA 20M on STAGE2;
6 ...... другие команды
7 ..... потом что то пошло не так и я решил установить заново для этого удалил лог в папке где лежит дамп а так же опять вызвал команду DROP USER STAGE2 CASCADE;
8 вновь п.1 но мне было сказано что это пространство уже есть

Comment: да всё соотвествует. спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... потому что в гугле не нашёл команды. Нашёл команду удалить юзера и якобы это автоматически удаляет схемы по юзеру

Так и есть, пользователь и схема в БД Oracle - синонимы, и связаны один-к-одному.

При импорте по умолчанию будут созданы пользователи из экспортируемой БД.
Утилита *Data Pump Import* (`impdp`) выполнит, например:

```
create user schema1 identified by schema1;

User SCHEMA1 created.
```

Просто из под учётной записи с достаточными привелегиями, выполните:

```
drop user schema1 cascade;

User SCHEMA1 dropped.
```